# ReactJS - How to change route in different component?

Tags: reactjs, routes, url-routing

I am quite new to ReactJS and its routing principles, have tried solving this issue myself but with no success and I am starting to wonder if it is possible to accomplish my idea.

I have an app like this :

```
<App>
  <Navbar />
  <MainContainer/>
</App>
```

Navbar :

```
<Navbar>
   <ul>
    <li>My Account</li>
    <li>Settings</li>
      .......
   </ul>
</Navbar>
```

Is there any possible way to change contents of MainContainer from Navbar ul option?

Comment: Are you using a routing library? (the most popular being [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start off by adding a routing library such as react-router-dom which is one of the most popular ones.

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

You can read more about it [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).

Now that you have the library, you can import the following in the App.tsx file (or in the file that you posted here) at the top:

```
import { Switch, Router, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

Those are one of the basics use of the routing library, but if we now would keep going with your file, then it would end up looking something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App>
    <Navbar />
    <MainContainer>
      <Route />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/my-acount" component={() => <MyAccount />} />
          <Route exact path="/settings" component={() => <Settings />} />
        </Switch>
    </MainContainer>
  </App>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In this case, your Navigation bar would look something like these:

```
<Navbar>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/my-account">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="/settings">Settings</a></li>
      .......
   </ul>
</Navbar>
```

And you might saw the `<MyAccount />` and `<Settings />` component inside

`<Route exact path="link" component={() => ...} />`

but the main goal is to put in the component (or function) you want to show when the user is redirected to that path. It can also be something like:

`<Route exact path="/my-account" component={() => return (<p>My Account</p>)}`

And a good feature to top it of with is the feature of sending the user to the top of the page when going to a new link/page. For that, you can add the following function inside `<Route/>` so that it results in something like this:

```
  const scrollToTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    return null;
  };

  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App>
      <Navbar />
      <MainContainer>
        <Route component={scrollToTop} /> {/* <-- here */}
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/my-acount" component={() => <MyAccount />} />
            <Route exact path="/settings" component={() => <Settings />} />
          </Switch>
      </MainContainer>
    </App>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

Comment: Why not use the `Link` component in the Navbar?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
[React router nav bar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607841/react-router-nav-bar-example)

I think it may be what you're looking for: it uses react-router, the most popular React routing library.